# Re-generate a random index until the indexed element is met the condition n times in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I know there have been a few similar questions regarding loop and random numbers, but I can't seem to find a solution for my problem.

Say I have a fixed list of numbers from my dataset and a threshold that the number has to meet:

```
x = (7,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39,41)
threshold= 25
```

I need to randomly pick a number from this list. Unfortunately, I cannot just directly loop over my original list, I'm forced to randomly pick an **index** of the list first, and find my number. So for example if I now randomly generate a index number `1` then I get `x[1]` which is `11`

The final result I need is to find numbers that are greater than the threshold for **at least 3 times** and then put all the resulting number in a list, then my loop can stop. (The indexes cannot repeat).
As an example, a possible final results would be `(27,29,31)` (The results can be in any format) . I'm thinking maybe something like this to start but really need help to proceed:

Comment: You randomly check any value is greater than threshold and you need to print 3 number greater than threshold, is it your ques?

Comment: You wrote "at least 3 times" but you are picking randomly so do you want to stop after exactly 3 numbers that are bigger then threshold?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
"Help me write this program" is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I will point out one immediate design discrepancy: you designed your major loop to execute 16 times.  Where in the functional requirements do you see this value of 16?  The only iteration-based limit I see is that you need 3 instances of meeting the threshold.  Your major-loop logic needs repair.

Comment: @LevM. yes I would like to stop after 3 times is met

Comment: @ashraful yes but final 3 results combined in a list

Comment: @Prune yes you are right..

Comment: Do you have to pick from 3 different indices? What if the same index that has a sutable number comes up twice?

Comment: @LevM. Yes I have to , I cannot repeat the same indexes, sorry I will add that on the description also

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are particularly concerned about the memory usage of creating an additional filtered list, the simplest would probably be to start by doing this:

```
filtered = [i for i in x if i > threshold]
```

You can then choose three samples from this filtered list (after `import random`).  The following will potentially choose the same item more than once:

```
random.choices(filtered, k=3)
```

or if you want to avoid choosing the same item more than once:

```
random.sample(filtered, k=3)
```

Each of the above functions will output a list.  Use `tuple(....)` on the output if you need to convert it to a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

First a clarification.  Do you need to pick a random element from the list each iteration, or do you need to pick a *different* random element from the list each time.  I.e., can the same index be picked twice?  You're doing the latter.

Second, you want to use `range(len(x))`.  You don't want to hardwire the length of `x` into your code, and you want index 0 to be a possibility.  `random.shuffle()` may be a better choice.

Lastly, you want to do something like:

```
result = []
for ....
    if select >= threshold:
        result.append(select)
        if len(result) >= 3: break
```

Comment: If this is a real problem, use @alani's solution above.  I was assuming this was some sort of HW problem, where they wanted to see that you could break out of a for loop when a condition was met.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume the following constraints:

1. We are not allowed to loop over the original list (including list comprehension)
2. We are only allowed to access one member of the original list at a time through its index
3. We must pick 3 distinct members of the list that are greater or equal to the threshold

The following code should satisfy all of them:

```
x = [ 7,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39,41 ]
threshold = 25

result_index = []

while len(result_index) < 3:
    index = random.range(0, len(x))
    if x[index] >= threshold and index not in result_index:
        result_index.append(index)

result = [ x[a] for a in result_index ]
```

Here is how this works:

- In the loop, we store indices, not the numbers them selves.
- For each index we check 2 conditions: there is a number there that is bigger or equal to the threshold **and** we haven't seen this index before.
- If the conditions are satisfied, we save the index, not the number!
- Repeat until we have 3 indices.
- Build new list by getting numbers from those indices directly.